# Noise resistant microcontroller used in high power inverters for PWM generating

Tags: microcontroller, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, power-electronics, inverter

In order to generate PWM pulses for driving switches of a high power(80 kW) three-phase inverter,which microcontroller family(and which member) is suitable? ,taking into account the noise effects on microcontroller operation due to switching.

Comment: PIC 5V family (eg. 16F series) is pretty good, but whatever family you use, you should use proper EMC electrical design, layout and construction (preferably 4-layer board or 2-layer with a very experienced designer). All connections off the board need attention.

Answer (score 6):

It's not about the microcontroller, it's about the circuit around it to keep nasty spikes off the micro.  This will require very careful attention to layout, proper grounding, and probably also shielding of critical parts.  This applies both to the emitters of the noise and the things susceptible to the noise.

The best way to deal with noise is prevent emitting it in the first place, or keeping it contained when you do.  After that it's designing everything else to be noise tolerant.  Part selection can help, but again, the real issue is good circuit design.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers and comments are sensible. Here is my opinion

to make the microcontroller more resistant to power spikes, isolate it from the spiky circuit. Use a separate power supply, and galvanic isolation (like optocouplers/capacitive couplers or transformers) to isolate the circuit, then on the power side, make sure that there is enough juice to drive the switches.

then after there is no normal conducting path for the noise to take, you can think about shielding.

to find the right one for your application I would start with mcus rated for automotive use, and then work up from there.